# extract id returned from spring and used in angular?

Tags: angular

```
upload(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.uploadfilef}`, formData, {
    reportProgress: true,
    responseType: 'json'
  });
  return this.http.request(req);
  
}
```

i have this issues that i want to extract the id from the object that i added it with the controller uploadfile and it actualy return the id but i can't used in angular

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that completely understand what your Problem is. If you want to access the data resulting in the http call you need to subscribe on the result of of your Obervable.

```
return this.http.request(req).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result); // http request response
  console.log(result.body) // the actual returned value from your call
});
```

If you can not work with your response data here you have to subscribe from where your method call was made.

```
upload(myFile).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result.body)
}
```

You should also try to utilize the types of typescript. Instead of

```
upload(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
```

you should create a new object which has the data of your response.

```
export class MyResponseObject {

  public value1: boolean;
  public value2: string;
  public value3: number;

}
```

and then replace any with your Object. It is usually much easier to work (spot errors) when the types are clearly defined. Well worth the time :).

```
upload(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<MyResponseObject >> {
```